# Can a UIViewController push a UITabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios

If so, how do I setup my UITabBarController in IB? All the examples I have seen create the UITabBarController in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am able to display the tab-bar controller modally

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UITabBarController` where you'd ordinarily use a `UIViewController`, but your users will be confused. Tab bar controllers are designed to be application-wide bars that switch between contexts.

Comment: i just tried it and got the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "test2ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: That message means that you need to set the view outlet in Interface Builder.

And I don't have sample code because I don't recommend doing it.

Comment: how can i set the view controller? IB wont let me drag.